# Помогите написать код для радиокнопки "и" в поисковике

Tags: php

```
<?php
$a=0;
$g=$_POST["search"];

$f = fopen("book.txt", "r");
$i=0;
if (strlen($g)==0){ echo  '<p>Clear</p>';}//если пустая форма
else{
if (strlen($g) <3){ echo  '<p>Short</p>';}//проверка на длину вбитых слов в поле поиска

else {

while(!feof($f)){
$str[$i]=fgets($f);
echo $str[$i]."<br>";
$i=$i+1;
}
echo "<hr>"; echo "<br>";

function dropBackWords($g) { //тут мы обрабатываем одно слово
    $reg = "/(ay|oy|a|ii|ai)$/"; //данная регулярная функция будет искать совпадения окончаний
    $g = preg_replace($reg,'',$g); //убиваем окончания
    return $g;
}

$form=explode(" ",$g);//разбиение вбитого в форму

$rez=array();//создание пустого массива
$l=0;//индекс для логики

switch( $_POST["and"] )

{case 'or':
foreach ($form as $b){
$b=dropBackWords($b);

    foreach ($str as $x)  {
        if (stristr($x,$b)==true)
        $rez[$l]=$x."<br>";$l=$l+1;     
        }
    }   
break;}

$result = array_unique($rez);//Убирает повторения
foreach($result as $o){echo $o."<br>";}

echo "<hr>";
} 
}

fclose($f);
?>
```

Comment: для кнопки "или" я написал

Comment: @Anton_14, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Comment: У меня есть 2 радиокнопки в поисковики "и" и "или". например, я ввожу в поисковую строку "информатика и математика" и выбираю кнопку "или". в моей библиотеке есть книги "информатика", но нет книг "математика". тогда он мне выдаст все кнопки"информатика", так как они есть в моей базе книг, а "математика" нет. В данном случае совпадение либо то, либо другое.
При нажатии радиокнопки "и" мой поисковик должен выдать все найденные книги "информатика и математика". вот это я и не могу написать.